# javascript, returning an array of smaller objects from an array of large objects

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of large (many elements) objects that look like this

```
{
    "id": "0165a74c-2545-40f7-9145-b95f5e5cb77e",
    "type": 4,
    "title": "My Title",
    "delete": false,
    "delete_reason": null,
    "delete_time": "2019-12-05T16:17:15.313Z",
    "count": 37765,
    "sync": 1575672973,
    "observe": 1575672949,
    "updated": true,
    "option": null
}
```

I can filter by type and get - the objects of type 'n' using obj.filter()

at this point i have an array of specific objects. but the object are still large.

I would like to have an array of objects that are JUST the title and ID.

```
[
    {
         "id": "0165a74c-2545-40f7-9145-b95f5e5cb77e",
         "title": "My Title"
    },
    ...
]
```

is there a way with map reduce to do this or will I have to resort to a for loop and do it that way??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could get only the properties by destructuring and map new objects.

```
result = array.map(({ id, title }) => ({ id, title }));
```

Comment: OI! perfect - thx, I had tried  couple variations of that concept, but obviously my syntax was off on some thing.
Appreciate the help!!